# How to get error message from pg_insert()?

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm using a PHP function `pg_insert()` to insert data to PostgreSQL. When the function return false, I can not get error message by `pg_last_error()`.(It works for `pg_query`).

Is there a way that I can get an error message from `pg_insert()`?

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it arrives too late. However I'll post something I just found dealing with the same problem.

When I use

```
$res = pg_insert($dbconn, 'mytable', $assocArray, PGSQL_DML_ESCAPE);
```

I don't get any error. However, if no options are passed,

```
pg_last_error($dbconn)
```

Displays the error properly. Could that be your case?